# get data from select statement with table name as a result of other query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not very perfect in SQL.
but I've got a scenario where I need to get data from the table which is the result of another query.

something like this:

```
select * from (select top 1 col from tableA)
```

where `top 1 col` contains the table name.

Sample data:

tableA:

```
col
tableB
```

tableB:

```
col
1
```

Comment: Then you need to use dynamic SQL.  Although I frequently use dynamic SQL in applications, there are often better solutions for more mundane tasks.

Comment: Do you mean the col column in tableA contains table names?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: If you mean col as table name you must build dinamically the sql command  (use a select result as table name is not allowed  in pure sql)

Comment: as @GordonLinoff mentioned dynamic SQL would work here - can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: I've edit my question and added sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200);
SELECT TOP 1 @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + col FROM tableA
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: perfect. That's what I want.